# AngularJS $q. Deferred queue

Tags: angularjs, promise, deferred, q

I have array (f.e. it is queue of files):

```
[{deferred: fileDef, data: file}, {...}, ...]
```

Each *fileDef* and *file* send to upload function which return *fileDef.promise* and call *fileDef.resolve* or *fileDef.reject* after uploading.

I want upload files in order: next file upload after previous file is loaded.

Now I use

```js
var queue = [];
var uploading = false;

//file input callback call each time the user selects files
function addAndUpload (file) {

  queue.push({deferred: $q.defer(), data: file});

  if (!uploading) recurceQueue();

  function recurceQueue () {
    if (queue.length) {
      uploading = true;
      var fileObj = queue.shift();
      upload(fileObj.deferred, fileObj.data);

      fileObj.deferred.promise.finally(function () {
        uploading = false;
        recurceQueue();
      })
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems bad. How to write better?

Comment: why dont u chain promise instead ??

Comment: Because I don't now queue size

Comment: What would happen if an upload fails? Does that just not matter?

Comment: See example: github.com/tamtakoe/oi.file/blob/master/oi.file.js#L251

Answer (score 10):

Don't use a queue and that boolean flag, just have one variable storing a promise representing all uploads. Also, your `upload` function should not take a Deferred object to resolve as an argument, but simply *return* a new promise.

Then the `addAnUpload` becomes as simple as

```
var allUploads = $q.when(); // init with resolved promise

function AddAnUpload(file) {
    allUploads = allUploads.then(function() {
        return upload(file);
    });
}
```

With the closure, you don't need that `queue` to store the waiting uploads any more. If you want `allUploads` to fulfill always, even if one `upload` fails, you need to return an always-fulfilling promise from the `then`-callback:

```
        return upload(file).then(null, function(err) {
            console.log(err, "does not matter");
        }); // fulfills with undefined in error case
```

Comment: See example: https://github.com/tamtakoe/oi.file/blob/master/oi.file.js#L251

I can't use promise in queue becase I need reject and resolve in transport functions

Comment: @tamtakoe: I don't see the problem with that?

Comment: no problem. I only think that my code unbeautiful because I use array of deffereds instead of array of promises

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using deferreds (internally), they work for this just like promises.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution to dynamically building queues with $q! You can always build a more complex wrapper for every single upload if you wanted to do more complex per-upload handling.

Comment: Note that $q.defer().resolve() does NOT return a promise (at least not on the current version of AngularJS), so the allUploads object has to be built in three steps;

 var queueDeferred = $q.defer();
 var queue = queueDeferred.promise;
 queueDeferred.resolve();

Comment: @ChristianRondeau: It doesn't? Ugh. Maybe more luck with `$q.when(undefined)`.