# How can I run promises in sequence and dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In my web application I can run blocks of code (it creates a promise and waits for the result to come out). Every time a user runs a paragraph, I add it's id to an array and run it sequentially.

```
runSequentially(paragraphsId) {
    paragraphsId.reduce((promise, paragraphId) => {
        return promise.then(() => this.runParagraph(paragraphId))
    }, Promise.resolve())
}

addToQueue(paragraphId) {
    if (this.state.runQueue.indexOf(paragraphId) === -1) {
        this.setState({
            runQueue: [...this.state.runQueue, paragraphId]
        }, () => this.runSequentially(this.state.runQueue))
    }
}

runParagraph(paragraphId) {
    const newParagraphResults = { ...this.state.paragraphResults }
    delete newParagraphResults[paragraphId]

    const newParagraphs = { ...this.state.paragraphs }
    const newParagraph = newParagraphs[paragraphId]
    newParagraph.isRunning = true
    newParagraph.status = 'running'
    this.setState({
        paragraphs: newParagraphs,
        paragraphResults: newParagraphResults
    })

    const paragraphs = [
        {
            identifiers: { id: paragraphId },
            title: newParagraph.title,
            source: newParagraph.source
        }
    ]

    const notebookLibraries = Object.values(this.state.notebookLibraries)

    this.runController = new AbortController()
    return this.service.notebookRun(this.notebookId, paragraphs, notebookLibraries, this.runController)
        .then(result => {
            Object.entries(result.paragraphs).forEach(entry => {
                if (entry[0] === 'default_paragraph') {
                    return
                }
                const paragraphId = entry[0]
                const paragraphResult = entry[1]
                newParagraphResults[paragraphId] = paragraphResult
                paragraphResult.exception ? this.setParagraph(paragraphId, { status: 'failed' }) :
                    this.setParagraph(paragraphId, { status: 'passed' })
            })
            this.setState({ paragraphResults: newParagraphResults })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
            const message = `Execution failed for reason: ${error.reason}.`
            this.handleServiceError('notebook', 'run', message)
        })
        .finally(() => {
            const newRunQueue = [ ...this.state.runQueue ]
            newRunQueue.shift()
            this.setParagraph(paragraphId, { isRunning: false })
            this.setState({ runQueue: newRunQueue })
        })
}
```

When a user runs a paragraph we call `addToQueue` which then calls `runSequentially`. We shift the queue when a promise is settled (in the `runParagraph` method) but if we run another paragraph before the first one has finished this will iterate over the same promise twice.

How would you handle this dynamic queue of promises ? Could recursivity work in this case ?

Comment: How about async/await? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute promises sequentially, passing the parameters from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082934/how-to-execute-promises-sequentially-passing-the-parameters-from-an-array)

Comment: @lukaleli I don't think it's a strict duplicate, since here the OP seems to want to be able to dynamically add to the queue and the question you linked is for a static array.

Comment: Can you please show the runParagraph() code as well? You could like, as I think you mean with recursively, not chain all the runParagraph promises together with a reduction and have the resolution of the previous promise, start running the next, so that you have time to remove a block from a queue. There's no reason to already make the promises if they have to wait for eachothers resolution.

Comment: @Shilly I have added the runParagraph code

Comment: Simple answer: promises do not run!

Comment: Consider: A promise chain is effectively a queue. 
By using a promise chain as your queue, instead of Array, then adding becomes trivial, "running" becomes automatic and the need for status flags should disappear. 
Initialise the queue with `Promise.resolve()`, then append `.then(successFn).catch(errorFn)` to cause `successFn` to run when the chain advances to that point. 
Unless you want errors to terminate processing, then ensure they are caught (and not re-thrown); if necessary, send some suitable default object down the success path to inform the next step in the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize another property (perhaps `queue` is not the best name since you already have `state.runQueue`) in your class to `Promise.resolve()`, and let that be the pending promise of your sequential queue. Then you can do something like this:

```
runSequentially(...paragraphsId) {
  this.queue = paragraphsId.reduce((promise, paragraphId) => {
    return promise.then(() => this.runParagraph(paragraphId))
  }, this.queue)
}

addToQueue(paragraphId) {
  if (this.state.runQueue.indexOf(paragraphId) === -1) {
    this.setState({
      runQueue: [...this.state.runQueue, paragraphId]
    }, () => this.runSequentially(paragraphId))
  }
}
```

`runSequentially()` now accepts incremental updates rather than the entire `runQueue`, and you shouldn't store `queue` on your `state` variable because the promise itself doesn't affect your render, so it's safe.

Answer (score 2):

> if we run another paragraph before the first one has finished this will iterate over the same promise twice.

You will need to keep the `promise` queue as a property in your state, instead of creating a new `Promise.resolve()` every time you call `runSequentially`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18952698/1048572) for an example implementation.

If you want to manage your queue strictly through `setState`, you should not need a `runSequentially` method at all. `runParagraph` itself would a) check whether it already is running and b) when finished dequeue the next element from the array and call `runParagraph` again until there a none left.