# how can I serialize an array of async operation in node?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

```js
const oldGet = Axios.get;
const promiseQueue: Promise<any>[] = [];
const serialGet = async (url: string) => {
  const curIdx = promiseQueue.length - 1;
  if (curIdx != -1) {
    await promiseQueue[curIdx];
  }
  const getData = oldGet(url);
  promiseQueue.push(getData);
  return await getData;
};
```

This is my solution for serializing http get method in node.
But it seems do not work, no matter `promiseQueue[curIdx]` is a resolved `Promise` or not, `await` will give up its execution.
It's there any solution meet my need?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18952698/1048572)

Comment: what is  promiseQueue[curIdx]? the array is empty

Comment: thank you all guys, I have solved this problem, I found that queue impl can't serialize the ops.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const oldGet = Axios.get;
let PrevPromise: Promise<any> | undefined = undefined;
const serialGet = async (url: string): Promise<any> => {
  const innerGet = async () => {
    if (PrevPromise) {
      await PrevPromise;
    }
    console.log(`get ${url}`);
    return await oldGet(url);
  };
  PrevPromise = innerGet();
  return await PrevPromise;
};
```

I solve this problem.